# How to install Phabricator on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, phabricator

I am trying to install phabricator on heroku. I used https://github.com/Aranatha/heroku-buildpack-phabricator buildpack to create my app. What else I need to do to able it to run on my app?

Comment: No, now I am using AWS for phabricator.

Comment: I've done the same :)